# Manifest service org.puredata.android.service.PdService makes app to close

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, puredata, libpd

I'm building a guitar tuner using Pure Data audio (https://github.com/libpd/pd-for-android).

The problem is when I add `<service android:name="org.puredata.android.service.PdService" />` in manifest, the app closes after I open in android emulator without errors. But it works on my real device.
Any ideas what is wrong?

The service code:

```
private final ServiceConnection pdConnection = new ServiceConnection() {
    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName name, IBinder service) {
        pdService = ((PdService.PdBinder) service).getService();
        try {
            initPd();
            loadPatch();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.toString()); //unable to open Pd audio: 44100, 1, 2
            finish(); // emulator always here.
        }
    }
```

In gradle I have this:

```
ndk {
    abiFilters "arm64-v8a", "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64"
}
```

and

```
implementation 'org.puredata.android:pd-core:1.1.0'
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This might be a problem with the emulator's microphone, and if it is, then it is not a libpd specific problem. To eliminate this option, I would try to answer the following:
1. Can you record audio with other apps on the emulator?
2. The PdTest sample app in the `pd-for-android` project also tests the microphone. Does the PdTest microphone test work on the emulator?